# iOS UISearchController TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` with a `UISearchBar` in the `NavigationBarTitleView`. When you start typing in the `SearchBar` a `ResultsTableView` appears. There is a cancel button that appears next to the `SearchBar` while typing and it correctly dismisses the `TableView`. So far so good.

The Scene's main viewController is a `TableViewController` that's connected to a `NavigationController` which is in a `TabBarController`.

Now, Everything works fine, except that when the `ResultsTableView` is displayed and you navigate away from that screen (via the `tabBar`) the screen becomes black when you come back to it.

I guess that I need to dismiss the `resultsTableView` when navigating away to prevent this (much like I do when a segue from the results is triggered) but i can't make it work.

Here's some code:

```
class PCFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: PCSearchTableViewController())

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let resultsTable = searchController.searchResultsController as! PCSearchTableViewController
        resultsTable.tableView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 64)
        resultsTable.tableView.frame.size.height = self.tableView.frame.height - 113
        resultsTable.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        resultsTable.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        resultsTable.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        resultsTable.parentController = self
        resultsTable.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "searchResultCell")
    }

...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.scrollsToTop = true

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Movies or TV Shows"
        self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        UILabel.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.lightTextColor()
        UITextField.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    }


...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PCMainDetailsTableViewController
        self.searchController.searchResultsController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.searchController.searchBar.text = nil
        destinationViewController.title = searchResult.title
        destinationViewController.movie = searchResult

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code for dismissing the search controller in `viewDidDisappear:`, something like this :

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)        
    self.searchController.searchResultsController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.searchController.searchBar.text = nil
}
```

Comment: I tried that just now... Still the same. http://s13.postimg.org/hc8k4skzb/Simulator_Screen_Shot_10_Dec_2015_13_18_07.png

Comment: So, I guess it worked, huh? Have you changed anythin else?

Comment: Actually I posted what I did, but this helped as well

Answer (score 1):

Okay... After quite a bit of fiddling around I was able to fix it.

The problem was that `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` don't get called when switching tabs.

To fix it I had to make a new class for the `TabBarController` and override the `didSelectItem:` method to call the `viewDidDisappear` method of the `PCFeedTableViewController`